ATTiny85 : how does it know it's to be programmed? (eg is it overvoltage, strange restart seqience, etc)
I am new to ATtiny MCUs and am in a bit of a chicken and egg situation. The ATtiny85 looks like it would fit my application, but I'd need to use all five signal pins (3 analogue in, 2 digital out). I'm considering programming it with a SparkFun PGM-11801 programmer (out of circuit). I don't need to know how it reprograms the MCU, but I want to make sure it still can after the first time I've programmed it and configured all the ports for my application.
Obviously, a deep dive into the programming process is beyond me at the moment and that's fine. I just don't want to brick it by reconfiguring pins in a way which makes it unreprogrammable. In hardware terms, what do I need to not interfere with in order to keep the chip reprogrammable?

It has six IO pins, not five. Which pins you intend to use and how?

I was planning on leaving "reset" well alone (even though it could be used for such as I read it, that looks very complex). Per the question, three analogue inputs and two digital outputs on physical pins 2, 3, 5, 6, 7 (in the DIL). Known as A1, A2, A3, 0 and 1, I believe, in the crazy numbering scheme. I am planning to program out-of-circuit, so the rest of the circuit doesn't matter.

@Justme - There are only five available if you wish to use easy low-voltage programming. Use of the reset pin requires HV programming.

To avoid bricking it the main thing is to avoid disabling the  Serial Programming Interface in the fuse bytes. If you do you will not be able to recover it with the programmer you have.


The ATtiny85 looks like it would fit my application, but I'd need to use all five signal pins (3 analogue in, 2 digital out).

That already sounds like you're at the upper edge of the capabilities range of an ATtiny85, and it's a relatively expensive lower-end microcontroller.

I don't need to know how it reprograms the MCU, but I want to make sure it still can after the first time I've programmed it and configured all the ports for my application.

Should be no problem: Since programming happens by working a serial bus while the reset line is held low, that can happen without your software having to cooperate. One caveat: you must not programmatically disable the programmability fuse: That permanently makes it impossible to program the memory that way.
The critical thing is that we don't know what you want to attach to your microcontroller. If the three pins you need to use for programming aren't "free" to be used, for example because some external amplifier controls the voltage on one of them, that can't work. So, in the end,

I don't need to know how it reprograms

is a bit wrong: you will need to know which pins you need to connect (and potentially disconnect to what external parts are usually connected).  You say you'll do that "out of circuit": That sounds like you're planning to use the DIP-8 variant of the chip and a socket. That sounds more expensive and error-prone than just using a much much more capable microcontroller with a less spatially wasteful package and pins on all four sides, giving you the freedom to leave the programming pins completely unused. For their capabilities and complexity of use, the DIP-8 variants are not as good a deal!
Of course, you could also incorporate functionality into your own software that accepts a new image from whatever you want. Self-programming is explicitly an option!
I'll say that these ATtiny are commonly used for very deeply embedded applications, i.e., things that will effectively never need a firmware update (for example, a battery safety cutoff controller: either it works correctly in the lab, or the whole device will need to be replaced in the field, anyways). If you want elegant reprogramming, and/or are not an expert in microcontroller software design, I'd say it'd be wise to start with something more tolerant, faster.
For example, the ATtiny85 in DIP package costs about 1.50€ to 2.00€, while it only has six pins, and a very meagre 512B RAM, and does a very limited clock rate of 10 or 20 MHz for very simplistic instructions; for the same money (actually, for less) you'd get e.g. an STM32G030F6P6TR, which not only is much faster, but also uses less energy for the same computation, can be programmed in-circuit because you get many more pins for free, a programmer costs less than 10€, and you get much much better programming interfaces, a proper debugging interface, and enough memory to store multiple versions of firmware, should you need to roll back an update. That all in a package that can still be very reasonably soldered by someone who knows how to solder through-hole chips, in a package that's slightly smaller than the (presumed) DIP-8 of your ATtiny85. And there's many choices that are easier to work with than an ATtiny and cost less than your choice of microcontroller. Buying ATtiny85's in 2024 makes most sense if you already have an established product with one, in my humble opinion. The up-to-5V IO is very rarely useful – no batteries for 5V exist, so you'd always add complexity stepping up supply voltages for it when running from a battery, you don't need 5V to switch transistors, and any external logic these days runs on 3V or less.

Thanks for your reply: I will digest. I do plan to use the DIP version, this is a one-off and, though it's a real (diy) application, I'm also using this as a way "into" using small MCUs. I don't have the time/money to set up schematics software, make sure I've the right design rules, use PCBWay etc, and I've long experience with knocking things up on stripboard and embedded programming (but not of modern electronic design). I agree for most people your direction would be right, though. Yes, just pulling it out a socket. I don't intend to reprogram often, but I'm sure there will be bugs!

Basically I am an old, existing product which would be expensive to upgrade to a modern design, Marcus Müller. :-D

"I don't have the time/money to set up schematics software" I'd very much recommend you try KiCAD, then. It's free, and they have a tutorial that should get you from naught to board in 20 minutes or so (it depends, obviously, on how strange you find KiCAD's concepts). However, I fully get your point! Stripboard indeed is a good reason to stick with DIP parts! I've solved the problem that there's few good DIP parts these days with so-called breakout boards. I'll say that modern "small" microcontrollers

can "feel" like the ATtiny series, or like the many 8051 clones (STM8, …), or they can be rather fully fledged MCUs, like the ARM cortex-M based one I mentioned in my answer. So, if you want to learn ATtiny, because it's a common thing to use in really tiny applications, cost-sensitive applications, but then typically in the non-DIP packaged ATtiny4 or such, by all means, go for the ATTiny85! If you want something reasonable to program that you find in things that do more than just blinking an LED or telling a host what kind of battery this is: maybe go for something less anemic as learning…

… as learning "goal"; I for example, for quick prototypes where +10€ doesn't matter, I tend to just buy Nucleo boards, like this, because I can plug them right in via USB, program them in place (the programmer is on-board) and if I ever feel like actually shrinking down a system, I just buy the microcontroller on them and do throw it on a custom designed board; all it takes are usually two or three decoupling caps, a 3.3V linear regulator (if at all), and the MCU.

The serial flash programming sequence for the ATTINY85 is described in section 20.6.1 of the datasheets.
Basically, the programmer pulls the reset pin low while twiddling the SCK, MISO, and MOSI pins. As long as your design does not prevent these pins from being used then you will still be able to program the chip.
This means, for example, if you have a normally-open button connected to SCK and LEDs with limiting resistors connected to MOSI and MISO then you will be able to program in circuit (although the LEDs will blink while you do it).
If you have, say, MISO connected directly to ground then you will not be able to program the chip in circuit.

